# Inserting values if they don't already exist - ORACLE/Postgres

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, liquibase

I have rollback in liquibase like:

```
<changeSet author="..." id="...">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="1">
                ...
            </sqlCheck>
        </preConditions>
        <delete tableName="A">
            <where>ID = 'house'</where>
        </delete>
        <rollback>
            <insert tableName="A">
                <column name="ID" value="house" />
                <column name="TITLE" value="a" />
                <column name="TYPE" value="b" />
                <column name="VER" valueNumeric="c" />
            </insert>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
```

and this changset is run in 3 different xml files, same for every file.

I need to provide custom sql query to rollback as it can throw exception about inserting same value to DB so I need to know wheter ID with given value exists.

I have made something like this:

```
<rollback>
            <sql dbms="oracle">
                insert into A(ID,TITLE,TYPE,VER)
                VALUES(house,a,b,c)
                where not exists (select ID from A where ID = 'house')
            </sql>
            <sql dbms="postgresql">
                ...
            </sql>
        </rollback>
```

I have made something like this, but it does not work. (I need to to this also for postgres) How can I do this? I need only to check whether ID with given value exists in 'A' table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `SELECT` as the source, not the `values` clause:

For Postgres:

```
INSERT INTO A(ID,TITLE,TYPE,VER)
select 'house','a','b','c'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from A where ID = 'house');
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=35678c5d370bf70232371d08d141d001)

---

For Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO A(ID,TITLE,TYPE,VER)
select 'house','a','b','c'
from dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from A where ID = 'house');
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c83bba737732d3e122c3c16f8f4fe6d4)

Comment: Why do I need `from dual` statement?

Comment: @mara122: because Oracle does not allow SELECT statements without a `FROM`

Comment: Okay, as I can deducde from your answer, that I cannot also use `values` clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO A(ID,TITLE,TYPE,VER)
VALUES(house,a,b,c)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from A where ID = 'house')
```

Should work for postgres

Comment: I checkded on online compiler for postgres and it throws 42601: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Comment: Could you post the link so i can work on another solution?

Comment: You can save your work and can send link, so i dont need to recreate your work.